# Rails 6 fails to integrate slick-carousel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, slick.js

I created a brand new project(rails 6.0.2.2). Now facing a problem
`testing.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function` after integrate slick

The way I integrate slick-carousel is:

- yarn add jquery(slick depends on it)
- yarn add slick-carousel
- in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

  - require("jquery")
  - require("slick-carousel")
  - require("packs/testing")
- in `config/webpack/environment.js`

```
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
 $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
 jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
})
)
```

sources have both jquery and slick-carousel, but `$('.testing').slick()` gives me the above error

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
```

Comment: have you required `require("slick-carousel")` in your `testing.js` file?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon
Tried, same error

Comment: Please check if testing.js referenced from application.js?

Comment: @Awlter did you solve this?

Comment: @MaysamTorabi Hi, I just downgraded rails to 5...